# How to contruct a PHP Array with entity name

Tags: php

How can i construct an array like below in php code

```
Array
(
    [Club] => Array
        (
            [title] => Test
            [passcode] => 000
        )

)
```

Comment: `array('Club' => array('title' => 'Test', 'passcode' => '000'))`

Comment: With questions like this, we will reach "20.Million.Questions" in no time.

Comment: Sorry mate..iam a java developer.......this stuff is different

Answer (score 3):

```
$arr = array(
'club'=>array(
   'title'=>'test',
   'passcode'=>600
 )
); 
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 $arr = ['club' => ['title' => $yourtitle, 'passcode' => $passcode]];
 print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Definitely, but you will have a bad time if, for some reason, your code ends up in a server with PHP version under 5.4

Answer (score 1):

```
$data['club'] = array('title' => 'Test', 'passcode' => '000'));
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
$data['club']['title'] = 'boyscout';
$data['club']['password'] = '1234';
```